# FLUTTER: How to use text widget inside a string

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of text widgets like this:

```
List<Widgets> widgets = [
    Text('Theo', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
    Text('Luca', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
]
```

and I have list of Strings like this:

```
'My name is @name',
'@name how old are you ?'
```

I want to replace the `@name` by a text widget in the list to print the right name with the right color.

Do you know a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in `Text` Widget, use `RichText` Widget which takes `TextSpan` as children.

Change `Text` to `Text Span`

```
List<Widgets> widgets = [
    TextSpan(text: 'Theo', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
    TextSpan(text: 'Luca', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
]
```

Each line is a `RichText`. RichText takes `TextSpan` as children where the text and the corresponding style has to be specified.

```
widgets.map((textSpan) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'My name is ',
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          textSpan // Name with color will appear here
        ],
      ),
      RichText(
        children: <TextSpan>[
          textSpan // Name with color will appear here
          TextSpan (
             text: 'How old are you? ',
             style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
           ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  )
}
```

Alternatively this can replicated by using Row and Text widgets but then it won't be a single line.

Answer (score 0):

you probably looking for rich text widget check this

[RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)